# Uso do Toggle() JQuery

Tags: jquery

Sou um programador iniciante, e estou tentando usar uma animação com toggle(), porem esta ate esta funcionando, exibindo e escondendo uma div específica, mas não ocorre a animação do toggle, gostaria que verificassem se a sintaxe está correta.

```
function toggle(idCliente){
    $("tr[id^='mostraDiv']").stop(false, true).slideUp("slow");
    $("#mostraDiv"+idCliente).stop(false, true).slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Comment: Essa ação de stop(false, true)  é quem toma as decições das ações de início ou fim da parada. O nome do método também esta errado, pois toggle é um nome reservado para métodos do jquery. Se vc quer fazer apenas um toggle, vc pode escolher o método $('...').toggle() do jquery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b24wx00d/ exemplo que tlz ajude.

Comment: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3481/criando-efeitos-de-fade-e-slide-com-jquery.aspx mais um exemplo, para desenvolvimetno